# Probability that at least one ticket is available

Tags: probability, solution-verification

I have an exam coming up and I'm working on exercises given in the textbook. Some of the problems had solutions but this one doesn't and I'm wondering if anyone can check my answer and help me out if I'm incorrect.

There are three shows: 1 on Friday, 1 on Saturday, 1 on Sunday. The probability that the shows are sold out are 0.16, 0.13 and 0.09 respectively. Assuming independecy of the shows, what is the probability that there is a ticket available for at least one show?

Is the solution P(at least 1 available) = 1 - P(all sold out) = 1-(0.16*0.13*0.09)?

Comment: This looks correct.

Comment: Yep, you are correct!

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses c: